# AWS SQS message not receive auto

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am working on aws sqs, send message is successfully but not received message not getting automatically.

Please help me.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;

$queueUrl = "";

$client = SqsClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '', //use your AWS key here
        'secret' => '', //use your AWS secret here
    ),

    'region' => 'us-east-1', //replace it with your region
    'version' => 'latest',
));

$result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
    'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl,
    'MaxNumberOfMessages' => 10,
));

foreach ($result->get('Messages') as $message) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo htmlentities(print_r($message['Body'], true));
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: $client = SqsClient::factory(array('key' => ' ', 'secret' => '', 'region'=>'us-east-1')); update config like this. NOTE: this function is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for replay.
After using your function display  error.

Comment: please post error?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))